# Netlify _redirects file not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redirect, proxy, netlify

I have my _redirects file in the public folder of my react app and I added a redirect rule `/*   /index.html  200`, which works perfectly.

Then I added another rule to proxy my app to my api server `/api/* https://tseapi.herokuapp.com/ 200!` it doesn't work.

the whole file looks like this

```
/*   /index.html  200
/api/* https://api.com/ 200!
```

As I stated, the global redirect `/*` overrules the `/api/*` and I couldn't get it to work.

NOTE: I have tried rearranging them like this

```
/api/* https://api.com/ 200!
/*   /index.html  200
```

and in this case, the app get's stuck on 'page not found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: I have tried rearranging them like this
>
> ```
> /api/* https://api.com/ 200!
> /*   /index.html  200
> ```
>
> and in this case, the app get's stuck on 'page not found'

You are stuck at 404 beacuse `https://api.com/` handles home route as a 404 from your backend(*when your url in Browser address bar is like: `/api/blah/blah`*).

With this rule `/api/* https://api.com/ 200!`, the asterisk (`*`) on `/api` is used to indicate anything that follows `/api/` to be matched to `https://api.com/`(*home route*).

**This is a problem** because what you want is `https://api.com/` matched to *anything that followed `/api/` as well*, for example;
**`/api/blog/2010` should be matched to `https://api.com/blog/2010`**.
But the current behaviour is *`/api/blog/2010` is matched to `https://api.com/`*

#### Solution

This is how your `_redirect` file should look like:

```
/api/* https://api.com/:splat 200!
/* /index.html  200
```

You need to specify **splat**.
Using an asterisk on the ***from URL(`/api/*`)***, you also need to indicate a **splat** on the ***to URL(`https://api.com/:splat`)*** that will map to anything that follows `/api/*`. So a URL like `/api/blog/2010` will be written to `https://api.com/blog/2010`

#### Bonus

The Netlify redirects engine will process the first matching rule it finds, reading from top to bottom.

So an ordering like:

```
/* /index.html  200
/api/* https://api.com/:splat 200!
```

Means that the first redirect rule(`/* /index.html  200`) will process since it always matches. The second one(`/api/* https://api.com/:splat 200!`) won’t be hit it, *even when browser address bar is like `/api/blah/blah`*. Even if you have `!` on a rule, the order of redirects is still followed.

**More specific rules should be defined at the top.** As shown:

```
/api/* https://api.com/:splat 200!
/* /index.html  200
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to post an answer after finding the :splat solution and making my config work fine. There isn't enough emphasis on the relevance on the :splat parameter in the docs and that caused me to easily miss it while studying.